# How to write a code that will create a progress bar in the title of the command prompt?

Tags: batch-file

Below is what I have tried already. If possible, I'd also like to make it happen slowly enough for the progress bar updates to be apparent, instead of just jumping to 100%, but quick enough that the update commands aren't apparent in the output

```
color 0a
%n=0
:start
if /L %n <100 (
%n+1=%n
title %n
goto start
)
else (
go to end
)
:end
echo finished
```

I recieved [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmssx.png), I don't understand what it's saying and why it doesn't work. Note that I wrote this in notepad and ran this as a batch file on windows.

Comment: read about batch file syntax! this ain't perl. there are tons of mistakes in your "batch file".

Comment: I think the question title could have just been **Create a progress bar in the title of the command prompt**

Comment: See `set /?` and in particular `set /a`. So `set /a n=!n!+1`. Then while fixing your current error your next error will be related to DelayedExpansion. See `for /?` and `set /?` for a discussion. See `setlocal /?` to turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to get you motivated.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "bar="
For /L %%a In (1,1,48) Do Set "bar=!bar!>"
Set "n=0"
For /L %%a In (1,1,23) Do Set/A n+=1
Set "i=0"
Echo( Processing files:
For /L %%a In (1,1,23) Do (
    Set/A i+=1, percent=i*100/n, barLen=48*percent/100
    For %%b In (!barLen!) Do Title !percent!%%  !bar:~,%%b!
    Echo( !i!- File%%a
    Timeout 1 1>Nul)
Title Press any key to exit . . .
Timeout -1 1>Nul
```

Just run it then try to work it out.